# How to include/exclude layout page based on the request type in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've an Index view and a layout page. My requirement is like-

> If I call the action method by just hitting the url in browser
>   directly then layout page should not apply on the Index view but if I
>   call the action method using AJAX call then layout page should be
>   applied on Index view.

Is that possible? I searched lots of places but didn't find the solution.

Comment: You return a `PartialView(...)` rather than `View(...)` (but that suggests you not doing things correctly if you need to update everything expect what is in the layout)

Comment: Actually it was an interview question which I were asked recently @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 1):

In your index view, just put the following line at the beginning

```
 Layout = ((Context.Request.Headers != null) && (Context.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")) ? "_Layout" : null;
```

This will check for the ajax header and set the layout to null if it is not found and set it to the layout if it is an ajax request.

Comment: Could you please let me know what is Layout here? any variable or something else which I need to declare in the view.

Comment: it is the name of the layout page under the Views\Shared folder. If your main layout/master page called _Layout then this is the name you should use